# how to run `find -exec` inside bash function --- problem escaping characters and unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, sed, find

I want to make it easier to run this kind of command:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's|wpp-splash|wpp_splash|g' {} \;
```

so I created a function in my `.bashrc` to shorten it:

```
function sedall() { find . -type f -exec sed -i 's|$1|g' {} \; }
```

this way I can do

```
sedall wpp-splash|wpp_splash
```

But there is a syntax error. I am not sure what it is, but that bash function is resulting in "unexpected end of file". I wonder if it is something with the `}` characters? I tried escaping them like `\{\}` but that did not solve the problem.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many problems there.

- Variables are not expanded inside single-quotes.
- `{ command ; }` requires the terminating semicolon (or a newline).
- `sedall wpp-splash|wpp_splash` That is understood as a pipeline because you did not protect the pipe character with quotes.

I would suggest this:

```
sedall(){
    [ "$#" = 2 ] || { echo Two arguments needed; return 9; }
    find . -type f -exec sed -i "s|$1|$2|g" {} \;
}
```

It needs two arguments instead of one, and it checks if those two arguments were given before execution.

```
$ cat a b
XABCX
YABCY
$ sedall ABC DEF
$ cat a b
XDEFX
YDEFY
```

Comment: Also a micro improvement can be to feed multiple found files to sed via the `+` keyword.As -i will treat each file individually.

Comment: Also care has to be taken that $1 abd $2 are properly escaped to be fit to be used on the LHS RHS of the s/// command respectively.

Answer (score 2):

```
function sedall() { find . -type f -exec sed -i "s|$1|g" {} \; ; }
```